# Confusion with terminology: Crepant resolution of terminal singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

In Theorem 1.1 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0009053.pdf) article, Bridgeland proves derived equivalence between Crepant resolution of threefold terminal singularities. I am a little confused with this terminology. In particular, a $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein variety $X$ is said to have terminal singularities if for any resolution of singularities $\pi: Y \to X$, we have $K_Y \cong \pi^*K_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y(\sum_i a_iE_i)$ with $a_i>0$ for every $i$, where $E_i$ are the irreducible components of the exceptional divisor. Then, how can such a singularity have a Crepant resolution (where every $a_i=0$)? What am I missing / misunderstanding?

Comment: Look up "small resolutions" (where the exceptional locus has higher co-dimension). Also, read the paragraph on page 1 where Bridgeland says "For simplicity..."

Comment: @onefishtwofish I think I understand. The article deals with small resolution. In these cases there are no exceptional "divisors" i.e., the codimension of the exceptional sets are larger than one. For example in the paragraph: "For simplicity...", the exeptional set is a curve, hence of codimension $2$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Try a simple example: xy=zw in C^4. It has a crepant small resolution